# Excel VB Advanced Filter Copy with Condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put a condition on each row copied. I want all uniques but only if they also have a specific value in another field.

This is what I have to grab all uniques (and it works) but I can't figure out how to get only the rows with a specific value in column J.

```
r1.Columns(20).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , Sheet11.Range("A1"), unique:=True
```

I have tried doing a CriteriaRange but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for it. Additionally I thought about an If statement but logically in my head it means it would fire off the whole list every time it has a true statement, not on a per row basis.

Here is how I thought it might work. But I get a type mismatch error.

```
r1.Columns(20).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, r1.Columns(10).Value = "November", Sheet11.Range("A1"), unique:=True
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your Criteria Range should be just that - a `Range` with the header corresponding to the column to be filtered, and criteria underneath. For example, `D1:D2` in this snapshot:

[image]

Secondly, you won't be able to copy just a single column (`20`) while filtering another column (`10`) in the same step.

You can tweak the Advanced Filter to

- First filter the entire list in place based on the criterion provided
- And then copy the visible cells in the column in question

Something like this (change `Sheet` and `Range` references as needed):

```
Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheet1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:B" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=.Range("D1:D2"), Unique:=True

        With .Range("B1:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
        End With

        .ShowAllData
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to keep the other parts of the code that worked perfectly. I added a hidden sheet and wrote a macro to copy the filtered results out to the new hidden sheet. Then I ran my original code against the filtered data on that hidden sheet.

```
Sub FilterLiveToDataSheet()
' Unhide Required Sheets
    Sheets("Original-Data").Visible = True
    Sheets("Filtered-Data").Visible = True

' Delete Old Data
    Sheets("Filtered-Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

' Copy Filtered Data
    Sheets("Original-Data").Select
    Range("TBL_ATTR_Spend[[#Headers],[HeaderName]]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TBL_ATTR_Spend").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, _
        Criteria1:="Delta"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

' Paste to Data Sheet
    Sheets("Filtered-Data").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

' Unfilter Original Data Page
    Sheets("Original-Data").Select
    Range("TBL_ATTR_Spend[[#Headers],[HeaderName]]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

' Hide Required Sheets
    Sheets("Original-Data").Visible = False
    Sheets("Filtered-Data").Visible = False

' Go to Results Sheet
    Sheets("Results").Select
```